allure report : after jenkins pipeline stage that generates allure report, the pipeline stopped, and next stage not being executed
i have ci/cd pipeline
the stages are :
checkout,
unit test,
component test,
playwright test ,
generate allure playwright test,
sonar,
lint deply,
etc
im refereing to the stages : playwright tests + generate allure
scenario 1: all tests passed, allure is being generated successfully, and all next stages are running ok
scenario 2: some of tests failed ( playwright stage is unstable), allure is being generated successfully, next stages ARE NOT being executed
scenario 3: some of test failed ( playwright stage is unstable), instead of generating allure report, im just printing "hello", inside the stage function of course, and the next stages are being executed
so, it means that somthing happens in the code that generates the report when it contains failed tests...
this is func of generating the allure report
        log.stepInfo("Generating allure report for playwright e2e tests")
        try {
        script.allure([
            includeProperties: false,
            properties       : [],
            reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
            results          : [
                [path: 'reports/e2e/*/allure-results/']
            ]
        ])
        } catch (e) {
            generate_allure_report_for_playwright_e2e_tests_rc.set(true)
            log.error("Error in Generate Allure Report For Playwright E2E Tests: ${e.getMessage()}")
        }
    } ```

notes that the stage of generate allure is always successed and never entered to catch
i cant paste here the whole pipeline as it long and complicated

any idea what could be the reason?
about plugin in jenkins, was installed already, maybe while was installed, it was installed diff? maybe uninstall and reinstall the plugin?

